# Convex geometry using differential forms

Tags: reference-request, convex-analysis, differential-forms, convex-geometry

I've been looking for papers or books that discuss/use differential forms in convex geometry. I have been very unsuccessful in my search and was wondering if anybody here had come across such literature?

My main interest in the area concern the theory surrounding the Brunn-Minkowski and Aleksandrov-Fenchel inequalities. Also practically anything about mixed volumes.

Appreciate any suggestions!